# load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libmaliinstr.so" not found simple http GET on device

Tags: java, android, device, loadlibrary

i was trying to make simple app that takes html code from website and it was making me crazy that it wasn't working...
i was testing it on my smartphone Zopo zp780 and when i accidently turned on an emulator it worked so can anyone please check this out if you have any clue what is this error...

This is my code:

```
public class Glavna extends Activity{

    TextView httpStuff;
    String brija;

    HttpClient client;
    HttpGet request;
    HttpResponse response;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tviter);
        httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);

        try {
            Log.e("test", "1");
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            Log.e("test", "2");
            request = new HttpGet("http://www.vogella.com");
            Log.e("test", "3");
            response = client.execute(request);
            Log.e("test", "4");

            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd;
            Log.e("test", "5");
            rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            Log.e("test", "6");

            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("test", line);
                httpStuff.append(line);
            }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


}
    }
```

And this is LogCat:

```
05-21 00:27:18.837: E/test(10993): 1
05-21 00:27:18.838: E/test(10993): 2
05-21 00:27:18.840: E/test(10993): 3
05-21 00:27:18.910: E/linker(10993): load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
05-21 00:27:18.918: E/(10993): appName=com.brija.hewbostonhttpbrija, acAppName=com.android.cts.openglperf
05-21 00:27:18.918: E/(10993): 0
05-21 00:27:18.918: E/(10993): appName=com.brija.hewbostonhttpbrija, acAppName=com.android.browser
05-21 00:27:18.918: E/(10993): 0
```

Isearched the web to download this libmaliinstr.so but i can't find that plus i don't know where to install it...please help

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a pervasive issue with some Asian-built devices. It occurs with my HTC Desire, and there are a couple of other SO threads which mention it:

[Library "libmaliinstr.so" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589959/library-libmaliinstr-so-not-found)

[library "libmaliinstr.so" not found.... in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065114/library-libmaliinstr-so-not-found-in-eclipse)

Despite it coming up as an apparent error in LogCat, I have never had an issue with an app not working because of this library not being found. I have therefore come to the conclusion that I can live without it, and so can my apps :)