# Library "libmaliinstr.so" not found

Tags: android, macos, scala, proguard

I have an Android app written in Scala. When I launch it the following error message appears in the log window:

```
08-31 13:11:10.781    5398-5398/my.app.app123 E/linker﹕ load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libmaliinstr.so" not found
08-31 13:11:10.784    5398-5398/my.app.app123 E/﹕ appName=my.app.app123, acAppName=com.android.cts.openglperf
08-31 13:11:10.784    5398-5398/my.app.app123 E/﹕ 0
08-31 13:11:10.784    5398-5398/my.app.app123 E/﹕ appName=my.app.app123, acAppName=com.android.browser
08-31 13:11:10.784    5398-5398/my.app.app123 E/﹕ 0
```

What does it mean and how to solve it?

Comment: Happens the same to me, have you found any solution or the cause to this error?

Comment: The same here with a chinese device. Android native app.

Comment: @daVe, mine is also chinese

Comment: have the same issue, also with a Chinese device, does someone found a solution?

Comment: could anyone found a solution to this problem. if so kindly share the solution.

Comment: same issue with Alcatel Idol2 - Not generating any problem in my app

Answer (score 13):

Scala is irrelevant.

I had also meet this problem before. It's a hardware problem with CPU. Found in some of Chinese phones. Huawei and xiaomi are known brands which devices may have this problem.

Load this library error occurs when application can't find a correct platform `*.so`.

From name `libmaliinstr`, I assume it related to [Mali](http://linux-sunxi.org/Mali_binary_driver) instrument [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mali_(GPU)). Mali is a low-level hardware driver, supporting enhanced OpenGL/GLES especially for browser rendering.

I reproduce it on CPU MT6582 (Hongmi 1S), which means this device missing a system lib `libmaliinstr.so`. So app can't use `openglperf` as usual.

Current solution:

Skip this device and ignore the error. (we may not have permission to modify a system library)

Addition:

You can disable hardware accelerate in these devices for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This code helped me to clear the problem

```
List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(yourIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
    this.grantUriPermission(packageName, yourURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
}
```

As told by `sakiM`, its a hardware problem with CPU in some phones. Adding to his list of phone brands, `Micromax` too has this problem. Thank you `sakiM` for pointing out the `Irrelevant Scala Problem`.

Note: If you are using fragment, you can replace `this` to `getActivity()` in the above given code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit `Pang`. But I'm not sure about what you've edited. Could you point me that, please?