# SSHing from an android app to a computer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ssh, wireless

I've followed some online tutorials on building an ssh app but unfortunately the resulting app compiles and builds fine but does not run properly. I'm trying to connect to a computer running ubuntu with a lenovo TAB A7. The IDE used is android studio. The computer has the ssh server installed and has been controller via SSH from other computers before. Any command I put into this app does not work. I have not touched the layout file as i'm just trying to send the ssh commands at the moment so it's just at the hello world default. Any help would really be appreciated !

The android manifest file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="robotics.c">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the activity java file is as below:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
public class mainmenu extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);
        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                try {
                    executeRemoteCommand("d46", "password", "192.168.0.209", 22);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute(1);
    }

    public static String executeRemoteCommand(String username, String password, String hostname, int port)
            throws Exception {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
        session.setPassword(password);

        // Avoid asking for key confirmation
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(prop);

        session.connect();

        // SSH Channel
        ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec)
                session.openChannel("exec");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);

        // Execute command
        channelssh.setCommand("nohup python /home/d46/catkin_ws/control/py_script/controller_walking.py");
        //System.out.print("cd /home/pi/Desktop | nohup python red.py");
        channelssh.connect();
        channelssh.disconnect();

        return baos.toString();
    }
```

The LogCat output is as follows:

```
 08-03 10:03:30.599 21960-21960/? E/cutils: to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)
    08-03 10:03:30.600 21960-21960/? E/cutils: to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)
    08-03 10:03:30.601 21960-21960/? E/cutils: to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)
    08-03 10:03:30.602 21960-21960/? E/cutils: to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)
    08-03 10:03:30.635 21960-21960/robotics.c E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    08-03 10:03:30.681 21960-21960/robotics.cW/asset: AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
    08-03 10:03:30.699 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16064: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
    08-03 10:03:30.699 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
    08-03 10:03:30.699 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16066: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
    08-03 10:03:30.699 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16070: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    08-03 10:03:30.700 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 477: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
    08-03 10:03:30.701 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 499: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
    08-03 10:03:30.709 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 268: Landroid/content/Context;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
    08-03 10:03:30.710 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 273: Landroid/content/Context;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
    08-03 10:03:30.710 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 274: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
    08-03 10:03:30.710 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 275: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
    08-03 10:03:30.710 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 277: Landroid/content/Context;.getDataDir ()Ljava/io/File;
    08-03 10:03:30.710 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 278: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    08-03 10:03:30.711 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 280: Landroid/content/Context;.getExternalCacheDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
    08-03 10:03:30.711 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 282: Landroid/content/Context;.getExternalFilesDirs (Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/io/File;
    08-03 10:03:30.711 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 285: Landroid/content/Context;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
    08-03 10:03:30.711 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 287: Landroid/content/Context;.getObbDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
    08-03 10:03:30.711 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 298: Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z
    08-03 10:03:30.747 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16496: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    08-03 10:03:30.755 21960-21960/robotics.cW/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 275: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
    08-03 10:03:30.761 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 440: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    08-03 10:03:30.761 21960-21960/robotics.c W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 442: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    08-03 10:03:30.775 21960-21960/robotics.c E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
    08-03 10:03:30.775 21960-21960/robotics.cW/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 148 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
    08-03 10:03:30.843 21960-21960/robotics.c E/linker: load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libmaliinstr.so" not found

                                                                      [ 08-03 10:03:30.845 21960:0x55c8 E/         ]
                                                                      appName=robotics.c, acAppName=com.android.cts.openglperf

                                                                      [ 08-03 10:03:30.845 21960:0x55c8 E/         ]
                                                                      0

                                                                      [ 08-03 10:03:30.845 21960:0x55c8 E/         ]
                                                                      appName=robotics.c, acAppName=com.android.browser

                                                                      [ 08-03 10:03:30.845 21960:0x55c8 E/         ]
                                                                      0
    08-03 10:05:00.907 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.201 (port 22) after 90000ms
    08-03 10:05:00.908 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:349)
    08-03 10:05:00.908 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
    08-03 10:05:00.910 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    08-03 10:05:00.910 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at robotics.c.mainmenu.executeRemoteCommand(mainmenu.java:44)
    08-03 10:05:00.910 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at rrobotics.c.mainmenu$1.doInBackground(mainmenu.java:24)
    08-03 10:05:00.911 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at robotics.c.mainmenu$1.doInBackground(mainmenu.java:20)
    08-03 10:05:00.911 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    08-03 10:05:00.911 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    08-03 10:05:00.911 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    08-03 10:05:00.914 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    08-03 10:05:00.915 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    08-03 10:05:00.916 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
    08-03 10:05:00.916 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.201 (port 22) after 90000ms
    08-03 10:05:00.917 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:176)
    08-03 10:05:00.918 21960-21981/robotics.cW/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    08-03 10:05:00.918 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    08-03 10:05:00.918 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    08-03 10:05:00.918 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:578)
    08-03 10:05:00.918 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:130)
    08-03 10:05:00.919 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:180)
    08-03 10:05:00.919 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:152)
    08-03 10:05:00.919 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:343)
    08-03 10:05:00.919 21960-21981/robotics.c W/System.err:     ... 11 more
```

Comment: there should be a library (Native) that can't be loaded/located `library "libmaliinstr.so" not found`, also failed to connect error `failed to connect to /192.168.0.201 (port 22) after 90000ms` could be caused by the issue mentioned above

Comment: I read that some phones/tablets dont have that library included and it doesn't affect the running of the application-thanks for the response through ! still totally stuck :(

Comment: looks like it's related to hardware https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589959/library-libmaliinstr-so-not-found

Comment: So I can't use this device? Even with hardware acceleration disabled it still throws up the errors :(

Comment: i am not sure, really, just found this in google

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using another device -a nexus tablet with an API of 22 as opposed to the lenovo tablet that had an API of 17 :) The software worked perfectly it was just a hardware fault.