# library "libmaliinstr.so" not found.... in eclipse

Tags: java, android

please help me. my Android application is an Alarm application that play on time in many Android devices, but my code has been error when played in some devices like Huawei Honor C3. the error is:

```
09-26 18:17:19.119: E/linker(23841): load_library(linker.cpp:759): library "libmaliinstr.so" not         found
09-26 18:17:19.121: E/(23841): appName=com.behroid.intelligentalarm, acAppName=com.android.cts.openglperf
09-26 18:17:19.121: E/(23841): 0
09-26 18:17:19.121: E/(23841): appName=com.behroid.intelligentalarm, acAppName=com.android.browser
```

please give me some solution...

Answer (score 1):

I guess some of the devices have missing library files. The same happened to me with opencl.so.
In that particular case I found the opencl.so file on the device and had to do a symlink opencl.so.1 to that particular apps appdata.(In the appdata folder in the root directory).

Comment: Hi, thanks, it maybe correct. My problem has this bug in some devices yet! :(